# How to close a toolbar when the material search view is open?

Tags: android, search, fragment

I am using a tab activity which has two tabs. I have a toolbar where the material search is placed.  I want to close the tabs when the material search is opened. Can any one help me out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO6bJ.png)

Comment: simple way set visibility gone to the tabs when searchview is opened and set visibility view when searchview is closed.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira If I make the set visibility off when the search is opened then, the tabs are becoming invisible but the layout is still there. I want that to be also invisible like the one happens in whatsapp.

Comment: You mean if you make tabs invisible viewpager still appears? if yes set visibility gone to the viewpager to.